# css background image doesn't repeat-x

Tags: css

I have a small problem on a website with a background element in CSS that doesn't go below a certain point on page. This is the link where you can see what I'm talking about, in the footer: http://www.stuffforyourdog.com/collegeadvisors/admissions.html

On other pages everything is fine, but on this one I can't figure out why the background image doesn't go all the way down, like it's supposed to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your background image's height is too small, if you set

```css
.tail-top2 {
    background: url(images/bg2.png) bottom repeat-x;
}
```

instead of top aligned, you can see that the page is too large for your image. You need to set your background image height to greater than or equal to your largest page height.